# Python and environment variables not working

Tags: python, linux

In a Docker container on Ubuntu, I'm running a `.sh` file which calls `python3 my_script_file.py`.  In that file, I do:

```
commands = []
commands.append("export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4")
commands.append("echo $OMP_NUM_THREADS")
```

I then execute the commands array with:

```
def execute_commands_list(commands, no_bash_script = False):
    for command in commands:
        if not no_bash_script and gc.output_to_bash_script:
            write_command_to_bash_script(command)
        else:
            print("     [  " + command + "  ]")

            ret = subprocess.call(command, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")

            assert ret==0 or ret==2, "bash return code error: " + str(ret) + " " + command
```

Here is the output:

```
     [  export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4  ]
     [  echo $OMP_NUM_THREADS  ]
```

(that's a blank line).  I try running echo $OMP_NUM_THREADS in the terminal after execution myself, and get nothing.  If I run those both commands manually however the env var is set.

(I have also tried os.environ, and that has failed as well)

What am I missing?

(For reference, the .sh file is:)

```
#!/bin/bash -p

python3 my_script_file.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because the scope of `export` is limited only to the current shell it's being running on. Meaning that only the shell the `subprocess` ran from, this environment variable will be visible to.

If you want to make this environment variable globally exposed, and given you're running from a linux machine of some sort, I'd suggest writing it to `/etc/environment` in the format of `KEY=VALUE`.

For example in your case, instead of

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
```

Replace it with:

```
echo OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 >> /etc/environment
```

**Note!** Since `environment` is located under `/etc` there's a good chance its permissions are set to allow write only to a sudo user, so make sure you include that in your `subprocess` call.

You can use something like the following:

```
echo 'OMP_NUM_THREADS=4' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment > /dev/null
```

`tee` prints the text to stdout, too. In order to mute it so it behaves more similar to shell appending (`>>`), route the stdout to `/dev/null`.